# I can't send an embed with a slash command (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So what happens is Anytime I try to send a embed with a slash command on discord.js it throws an error.
Here is the "help.js" file I'm trying to send.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const helpEmbed = {
  "type": "rich",
  "title": `Need Help?`,
  "description": `Here you go.`,
  "color": 0x00fff0
}

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('help')
        .setDescription('Prints a Help Message'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await channel.send({embeds: [helpEmbed]});
    },
};
```

The Error:

```
ReferenceError: channel is not defined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\commands\help.js:37:3)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\index.js:31:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:83:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my-bot\bot-file\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the variable `channel` has not been defined before you used it. Instead you can use `interaction.channel.send()` if you want to send the help embed to the channel where the user used the slash command or optionally you can fetch the channel by either using the id or the channel name and then send it.

1st option: (If you want to send the embed to the channel where the user used the slash command)

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.channel.send({embeds: [helpEmbed]});
}
```

2nd option: (If you want to find the channel by its id or its name)

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get('channelid')
    // Or
    const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'channelName')
    await channel.send({embeds: [helpEmbed]});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This went perfectly fine. However, when the bot sends the embed with "The application did not respond" ephemeral message. Is there any way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: The reason you are getting that is because you need to reply to the interaction instead of sending the embed to the channel. Instead of `interaction.channel.send()`, try `interaction.reply()`